# How to load different html pages with JavaScript, triggered by the user, clicking on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know it's probably simple to handle, but seems that not for silly boy like me.

Here is the deal:

I am trying to load 3 different html pages, depending on 3 different buttons for a user to select.

It only displays button selected but when I try to click book button I see error 405.

Thanks in advance to everyone guiding me through what am I doing wrong =)

```js
let bookBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
let bookNow = document.getElementById("book-btn-widget");
let bicycleBtn = document.getElementById("bicycle");
let carBtn = document.getElementById("car");
let vanBtn = document.getElementById("van");

// Transport selection buttons trakcer
for (var i = 0; i < bookBtns.length; i++) {
  bookBtns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
  var current = document.getElementsByClassName("icon-active");
  if (current.length > 0) { 
    current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" icon-active", "");
  }
  this.className += " icon-active";
  });
}

bookNow.click = function() {
  if (carBtn.classList.contains("icon-active")) {
    location.href = "file:///Users/apple/Desktop/AnyRuns%20Project/car-quote.html";
  } else if (vanBtn.classList.contains("icon-active")) {
    location.href = "./van-quote.html";
  } else {
    location.href = "./bicycle-quote.html";
  }
};
```

```css
.transport-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.bicycle-icon,
.car-icon,
.van-icon {
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 110px;
    border: 2px solid #13985C;
    transition-duration: 1s;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.icon-active {
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #13985C;
    color: #fff;
    border: 2px solid #13985C;
}

.fa-biking,
.fa-car,
.fa-truck {
    font-size: 15px;
    
}

.book-button {
    background-color: #13985C;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    padding: 9px 23px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="transport-required-section">
                      <h4 class="delivery-headings">Transport required</h4>
                      <div class="transport-buttons">
                          <div class="bicycle-icon btn icon-active"><i class="fas fa-biking" id="bicycle"></i> Bicycle</div>
                          <div class="car-icon btn" id="car"><i class="fas fa-car"></i> Car</div>
                          <div class="van-icon btn" id="van"><i class="fas fa-truck"></i> Van</div>
                      </div> 
                  </div>
                  <div class="vl"></div>
                  <div class="booking-section">
                      <button id="book-btn-widget" class="book-button" onclick="location.href = 'bicycle-quote.html';">Book Now</button>
                  </div>
```

Comment: 405, as in Method Not Allowed? That is usually what you get when you try to make a POST request to a static resource - but you are using `location.href = …` here, so that will only cause GET requests.

Comment: Why is the first case using a `file:///` URL?

Comment: I've changed to GET method, now I don't get the 405, but the page just reloads. Regarding first case I was just playing around, searching answers by myself.

Comment: Ah, so you actually submitted your form, which cancelled any processing of the JS logic. A `button` by default is a _submit_ button, if you don’t want it to submit the form, then add `type="button"` to it.

Comment: And remove the `onclick` attribute from it, otherwise you’ll have _two_ event handlers trying to do different things on your button here.

Comment: Still nothing happens, though I see in the console that this code snippet started identifying if the element has the class of active returning true or false accordingly. But I just click and nothing happens at all. Maybe there is a better way to create such functionality?

Comment: `bookNow.click = function()` would need to be `bookNow.onclick = function()`. But why are you using different syntaxes of adding event handlers in the first place? You already used `bookBtns[i].addEventListener("click", …` before.

Comment: You've helped me! How can I thank you, kind man? I am learning js for a while. I know the theory good as well but when things come to practice sometimes I get stuck not knowing what way should be best for task accomplishment. That's why I go reckless playing around around with syntaxes. Thank you so much once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this code to go to a page within 3 seconds. Maybe you could alter it with the onclick function so that when you press on the button, you'll immediately go to the page you want to go to. (Setting the setTimeout at 1 ms (E.G.) or completely removing it.

```
  <script>
             setTimeout(function(){
                window.location.href = 'https://kapsalonyazanonline.nl/';
             }, 3000);
          </script>
```

Comment: I was helped to handle this in comments. You are right. It has worked out with onclick function instead of click.